# Disk Utility Showing 0 Bytes on USB

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, terminal

I have a 32GB USB. I recently used `dd` to write a Linux image to the USB. Somewhere during `dd` my Macbook froze.

When I plugged it back into the laptop after rebooting it wouldn't show. I left it 20 minutes and it finally said the disk cannot be read.

It shows in disk utility, but the drive name is `0958342385823429` and the info on the drive is as follows:

```
Name :  Generic USB Flash Disk Media
Type :  Disk

Partition Map Scheme :  Unformatted
Disk Identifier :   disk1
Media Name :    Generic USB Flash Disk Media
Media Type :    Generic
Connection Bus :    USB
Device Tree :   IODeviceTree:/PCI0@0/XHC1@14
Writable :  Yes
Ejectable :     Yes
Location :  External
Total Capacity :    0 Bytes
Disk Number :   1
Partition Number :  0
S.M.A.R.T. Status :     Not Supported
```

I can't format the drive, I've tried partitioning within disk utility and in the terminal using `fdisk` to no avail. Here's some more information:

```
fdisk /dev/disk1
Disk: /dev/disk1    geometry: 0/4/63 [1 sectors]
Signature: 0x0
     Starting       Ending
 #: id  cyl  hd sec -  cyl  hd sec [     start -       size]
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused      
 2: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused      
 3: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused      
 4: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused  

fdisk:*1> disk
Disk: /dev/disk1    geometry: 0/4/63 [1 sectors]

sudo fdisk -d /dev/disk1
0,0,0x00,-,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0x00,-,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0x00,-,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0x00,-,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you erase it using diskuitl

```
diskutil eraseDisk JHFS+ "name" /dev/disk1
```

or repartition it.

```
diskutil partitiondisk /dev/disk1 JHFS+ newdiskname 100%
```